# Android persisting data - Serialization vs Jackson+JSON

Tags: android, json, performance, serialization, jackson

My Android app stores data using ObjectOutputStream in files. We made a conscious decision to not use a DB. I've read up recently that Serialization on Android is considered very slow. Also, that using Jackson + JSON is considered fast.
However after incorporating Jackson/JSON it seems that storing POJOs in files with Jackson/JSON is not at all faster and sometimes even slower that Serialization. I'm using the core library for Jackson v2.2

I've also tried using `ObjectWriters` and `ObjectReaders`, but that doesn't provide any significant speed benefit.
I'm using the following settings for `ObjectMapper` (I create one globally):

```
mapper.setVisibility(JsonMethod.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
mapper.setVisibility(JsonMethod.GETTER, Visibility.NONE);
mapper.setVisibility(JsonMethod.SETTER, Visibility.NONE);
mapper.setVisibility(JsonMethod.IS_GETTER, Visibility.NONE);
mapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.USE_ANNOTATIONS, false);
mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.USE_ANNOTATIONS, false);
```

When I say that there is no speed benefits what I'm timing is taking about ~400 POJOs and storing them in separate files. I'm currently timing Serializtion and writing to files as opposed to the opposite. Half of these POJOs are rather complex (with references to lists of other POJOs). I'm testing on a device (Galaxy Tab 10-1 running Android 4.1). With both Serialization and Jackson/JSON the process takes about 6 seconds with difference between the two approaches following within margin of error (variation on repeated test runs).

Any advice on how it's possible that "very slow Serialization" on Android could be roughly the same as "very fast" Jackson/JSON? Is there some approach that could significantly speed up Jackson?